# totally bounded + completness implies every open cover has finite subcover

Tags: real-analysis

prove that totally bounded + completness implies every open cover has finite subcover.

anyone has any ideas? im not too sure how to do this?

maybe start with totally bounded to say that to get an epsilon-net and then get an element from the epsilon net in order to construct a sequence? eventually radius keeps getting smaller and smaller, say epsilon=1/2, and then 1/4, ..., 1/2^n?

Comment: Suppose there were an open cover $\mathscr{U}$ without finite subcover. Cover the space with finitely many closed balls of radius $1$. At least one of them cannot be covered by finitely members of $\mathscr{U}$, call it $B_1$. Cover $B_1$ by finitely many closed balls of radius $1/2$. At least one of them cannot be covered by finitely many members of $\mathscr{U}$, call it $B_2$. Cover $B_2$ by ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sketch of a proof that a complete, totally bounded metric space is sequentially compact. You can either directly prove your result using these ideas, or you can prove this result and then prove that a sequentially compact metric space is compact.

Suppose $K$ is a complete and totally bounded metric space. Take a sequence of nets $\left \{ \left \{ B_{k,n} \right \}_{k=1}^{m(n)} \right \}_{n=1}^\infty$. Here $\left \{ B_{k,n} \right \}_{k=1}^{m(n)}$ is a $1/n$-net for $K$.

Now let $\{ x_j \}_{j=1}^\infty \subset K$ be a sequence. Then for every $n$ there is a $B_{k(n),n}$ such that $x_j \in B_{k(n),n}$ for infinitely many $j$. This follows from the pigeonhole principle. So we can extract a Cauchy subsequence by diagonalization. Then this sequence is convergent by completeness.

Note that this only uses completeness at the end, so we get another theorem for free: a totally bounded subspace of a complete metric space is precompact (i.e. has compact closure).